# GSM Module SIM7600E-H-4G-HAT is not logging in to the Network

Tags: networking, gps, gsm, lte

I need help at my GSM-Project. Somehow I am not able to connect to the Network. I already checked if I forgot something, but I don't think so. The LTE- and GPS-Antenna are connected correctly to the board and a valid SIM(my own for testing, without PIN) is inserted. I did manage to receive a Message and get some GPS-Informations(which had a little deviation). The "NET" indicator LED keeps flashing fast, which tells me that the module hasn't logged in to the Network, but I couldn't it explain to myself.

Here is a link to the module's Manual:

[SIM7600E-H-4G-HAT-Manual](https://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/6/6d/SIM7600E-H-4G-HAT-Manual-EN.pdf)

Comment: There are plenty of reasons that prevent your module from *registering* to the network. You should edit your question being more precise about what you tried (so that we can figure out what you forgot)

Comment: What if you provide `AT+CEREG?` command? It is the registration status on LTE packet network

Answer (score 0):

Try the AT+CREG? command to check the status of network registration.

Comment: The module responses with "+CREG: 0,1". The first parameter means: "disable network registration unsolicited result code", the second "registered, home network". Does this mean I am connected to the "global" network? Yesterday i checked if I can ping the google-Server. This worked out, but I am still confused, because the "NET" LED indicates that the module shouldn't be logged in to the network. The LED is flashing 1 time per second, but it should flash 1 time every 3 seconds.